# Удаление данных из массива пользователем

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть массив `let arr=[1,2,3]` и есть задача чтобы пользаватель заходил на веб страницу и ему выводилось соообщение с последним значением из массива «3» а после это значение из массива удалялось, и в следующий раз заходя на веб страницу другому пользователю выводилось уже «2». 
С помощью чего и как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Хранить массив в localStorage например

Comment: А разве так можно? Насколько мне известно там можно только ключ и значение хранить? Значение может быть массивом?

Comment: @Вы можете реализовать это либо при использовании любого файла, либо БД.

Comment: Извините, не понял, использование файла использовать как условие удаления? А БД это база данных?

Comment: @Tryr значение может быть только строкой, но вам никто не запрещает преобразовывать массив в строку и обратно

Comment: А разве у строки можно удалить последнее значение?

Comment: @Tryr почему бы и нет

Comment: Ну ключевое слово в вопросе - `другому пользователю`. Это реализуемо только на стороне сервера... localStorage у каждого свой, один посетитель не может без участия сервера увидеть, что там творилось у предыдущего.

Comment: То есть без баз данных никак не обойтись? :(

Comment: Ах да, на слово «другому» я как-то и не обратил внимание. Тогда да, неизбежно придётся изобретать хранилище, к которому будет какой-либо доступ у всех пользователей, вроде той же БД на сервере

Comment: Эх, хорошо, большое спасибо за помощь!